# Resetting a black menubar to white?

Tags: menu-bar, windows, hulu

When I run Hulu Desktop (and certain other programs), they turn the menubar dark (and turn on auto-hide), but they don't put it back to normal when they are done.

Is there a way of resetting the menubar to white (and turning off auto-hide) without having to log out and log back in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone has this problem and doesn't have Nocture, you should be able to fix it by running the following Terminal command:

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

This restarts the process responsible for drawing the menu bar. It should fix almost all menu bar-related problems.

Comment: Just tried it, but although the clock etc. disappear for a second, the menubar still stays black.

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried this (haven't experienced the problem you mention), but I suspect if you open the **System Preferences** and choose **Desktop & Screen Saver**, checking and then unchecking **Translucent menu bar** will force it to redraw and fix itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion---I tried it, but it doesn't work.  (it turns translucent and back, but stays dark and auto-hide stays on)

Answer (score 0):

I too have Hulu Desktop but I never see the menubar turn dark before.  My Hulu Desktop version is 0.9.10 (which is currently the most up to date version).  I go with what @MatthewFrederick said above and turning off and on the Translucent Menu Bar option.

Another thing you can do is to see if another program isn't causing the menubar to go dark.  I looked through the Hulu Desktop settings and there wasn't any option for turning the menubar dark.  I know I have some third party apps that would make my Mac perform certain functions when I run other apps.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question...

The cause of the black menubar turned out to be running 'nocturne'.  It's sufficiently useful that I'll keep using it, and switching to 'night' and back resets the menubar to white without having to log out (going back to the login window from the 'switch users' menu also resets it).

Answer (score 0):

I found that simply clicking on the notification centre in the top right hand corner, next to spotlight fixed it instantly without messing about. Hope this helps